# What is the default setting (log handler, log level, log format) for child logger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

When I create a child logger using `logging.getLogger(__name__)`, then does it have a default log handler, log level, log format?

Answer (score 0):

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print(log.__dict__)  # this gives attributes dictionary
```

Output:

`{'filters': [], 'name': '__main__', 'level': 0, 'parent': <RootLogger root (WARNING)>, 'propagate': True, 'handlers': [], 'disabled': False, '_cache': {}, 'manager': <logging.Manager object at 0x000001ECCF434520>}`

```
print('value of level attribute (i.e. log level) is: ',log.__getattribute__('level'))  # this gives value of individual attributes
```

Output:

`value of level attribute (i.e. log level) is:  0`   Here log level `0` represents `NOTSET`

check https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html for detailed information.